# Order of Custom Elements Execution

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I have created webcomponents using customElements.

```
<x-select>
     <x-option>India</x-option>
     <x-option>Africa</x-option>
</x-select>
```

Order of execution would be, at first constructor of `<x-select>` is called and then the constructor of `<x-option>` is called. But, I want `<z-option>` 's constructor to be called first before `<z-select>`. How could I achieve that?

Comment: what exactly you want clear it ??

Answer (score 3):

There are several factors for the order of operations with web components.

When a component with inner elements is created then the outer constructor will be called first. Then the inner constructors are called. This is normal.

If the component is NOT in a real DOM tree then nothing else will happen. No other code is called.

Once the component is placed into the DOM then the `connectedCallback` is called. Starting from the outside component and then the inside components.

Here is an example not using shadow DOM:

```js
// Class for `<x-select>`
class XSelect extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('x-select constructor');
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('x-select connectedCallback');
  }
}

// Define our web component
customElements.define('x-select', XSelect);

// Class for `<x-option>`
class XOption extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('x-option constructor');
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('x-option connectedCallback');
  }
}

// Define our web component
customElements.define('x-option', XOption);
```

```html
<x-select>
  <x-option>India</x-option>
  <x-option>Africa</x-option>
</x-select>
```

The console output is:

```
x-select constructor
x-select connectedCallback
x-option constructor
x-option connectedCallback
x-option constructor
x-option connectedCallback
```

Even when using shadow DOM in `<x-select>` the order of operations is the same:

```js
// Class for `<x-select>`
class XSelect extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    var sd = this.attachShadow({mode:'open'});
    sd.innerHTML = '<slot></slot>';
    console.log('x-select constructor');
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('x-select connectedCallback');
  }
}

// Define our web component
customElements.define('x-select', XSelect);

// Class for `<x-option>`
class XOption extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('x-option constructor');
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('x-option connectedCallback');
  }
}

// Define our web component
customElements.define('x-option', XOption);
```

```html
<x-select>
  <x-option>India</x-option>
  <x-option>Africa</x-option>
</x-select>
```

If we create the components in JavaScript then we can control the order of construction. In my example below I am creating them in the same order, but you can mix that up if you want.

```js
// Class for `<x-select>`
class XSelect extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    //var sd = this.attachShadow({mode:'open'});
    //sd.innerHTML = '<slot></slot>';
    console.log('x-select constructor');
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('x-select connectedCallback');
  }
}

// Define our web component
customElements.define('x-select', XSelect);

// Class for `<x-option>`
class XOption extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('x-option constructor');
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    console.log(`x-option[${this.textContent}] connectedCallback`);
  }
}

// Define our web component
customElements.define('x-option', XOption);

console.log('creating x-select');
var xs = document.createElement('x-select');

console.log('creating x-option 1');
var xo1 = document.createElement('x-option');
console.log('setting text of x-option 1');
xo1.textContent = 'India';

console.log('creating x-option 2');
var xo2 = document.createElement('x-option');
console.log('setting text of x-option 2');
xo2.textContent = 'Africa';

console.log('Adding x-option 1 to x-select');
xs.appendChild(xo1);

console.log('Adding x-option 2 to x-select');
xs.appendChild(xo2);

console.log('Adding x-select to container');
var c = document.getElementById('container');

c.appendChild(xs)
```

```html
  <div id="container"></div>
```

The constructors are called when I call `document.createElement` but the connected callback will not trigger until the elements are placed into the DOM.

The console output of the above code is:

```
creating x-select
x-select constructor
creating x-option 1
x-option constructor
setting text of x-option 1
creating x-option 2
x-option constructor
setting text of x-option 2
Adding x-option 1 to x-select
Adding x-option 2 to x-select
Adding x-select to container
x-select connectedCallback
x-option[India] connectedCallback
x-option[Africa] connectedCallback
```

One final example is to create a DIV, then set its `innerHTML` to this:

```
<x-select>
  <x-option>India</x-option>
  <x-option>Africa</x-option>
</x-select>
```

```js
// Class for `<x-select>`
class XSelect extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    //var sd = this.attachShadow({mode:'open'});
    //sd.innerHTML = '<slot></slot>';
    console.log('x-select constructor');
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('x-select connectedCallback');
  }
}

// Define our web component
customElements.define('x-select', XSelect);

// Class for `<x-option>`
class XOption extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('x-option constructor');
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    console.log(`x-option[${this.textContent}] connectedCallback`);
  }
}

// Define our web component
customElements.define('x-option', XOption);

console.log('creating div');
var d = document.createElement('div');

console.log('setting innerHTML of div');
d.innerHTML = `<x-select>
  <x-option>India</x-option>
  <x-option>Africa</x-option>
</x-select>`;

console.log('Adding div to container');
var c = document.getElementById('container');

c.appendChild(d)
```

```html
  <div id="container"></div>
```

This now only calls the constructors of the outer element and then the inner elements. Only after the `<div>` is placed into the DOM are the calls to `connectedCallback` called. And, again, these are called for the outside element first, then the inside. elements.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of achieving that.

**Via Javascript**

1° Create the `<x-option>`s:

```
xo1 = document.createElement( 'x-option' )
```

2° Create the `<x-select>`

```
xs = document.createElement( 'x-select' )
```

3° Append the `<x-option>`

```
xs.appendChild( xo1 )
```

**Via HTML**

Defer the init of the parent element in another custom element method, not in its `constructor()`. Then call this method afert the child elements are created.

```
<x-select id="xs">
    <x-option>India</x-option>
    <x-option>Africa</x-option>
    <script>xs.init()</script>
</x-select>
```

```html
<script>
class XSelect extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    console.log('x-select created')
  }
  init() {
    console.info('x-select init')
  }
}
customElements.define('x-select', XSelect)

class XOption extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    console.log('x-option created')
  }
}
customElements.define('x-option', XOption)
</script>

<x-select id="xs">
  <x-option id="1">India</x-option>
  <x-option id="2">Africa</x-option>
  <script>xs.init()</script>
</x-select>
```