# Can I make functional HTML elements, perhaps using custom HTML elements?

Tags: html, lisp, element

I want to make functional HTML elements, by which I mean elements which return a function of the HTML inside them before the page is rendered, so that HTML becomes like LISP.  For instance, if the HTML says this:

```
<setf>
  <var-name>X</var-name>
  <list>
    <li>a large red box</li>
    <li>an iron key</li>
    <li>a mangy cat</li>
  </list>
</setf>

You see
<foreach> <var-name>EL</var> <var-val>X</var-val>
          <div><var-val>EL</var-val>,</div>
</foreach>
```

I want "setf" to be a custom tag which performs the function of setting the value of a variable named "X" to the given list, and I want "foreach" to be a custom tag which evaluates the HTML code inside it, outputting in sequence the result of its function for each value EL in the list X:

```
You see a large red box, an iron key, a mangy cat,
```

which is then rendered as HTML.
(I did not fix the bug with the final comma to keep the example simple.)

And of course I want to be able to define or redefine tags on the fly, as in LISP:

```
<defun>
  <var-name>reverse</var-name>  <!-- reverse a list -->
  <list> <var-name>X</varname> </list>  <!-- the argument list, which is a single list -->
  <if> <null> <var-val>X</var-val> </null>
    <then> <nil /> </then>
    <else>
      <cons> <reverse> <cdr> <var-val>X</var-val> </cdr> </reverse> <car> <var-val>X</var-val> </car> </cons>
    </else>
  </if>
</defun>
```

... which will not work as written, because evaluation is done from the bottom up, so the `<reverse> ... </reverse>` bit of code would be evaluated before the enclosing function definition of 'reverse' is evaluated.  It is important to be able to define recursive functions, but I don't know how.

I would also like to be able to specify for each tag whether the evaluation is performed server-side or client-side.  Though if it can be done only on one or the other, I could live with that.

Is there any way at all of doing this?  It would make it much easier to do simple computations all within a single place in the HTML, rather than splitting it up across different pages and scripts written in different languages.

Comment: This comment should not have been closed as "opinion-based".  It is not asking for an opinion between known alternatives.  It's asking whether or not it is technically possible, in any way at all, to write HTML code in which some HTML tags act as functions.

Comment: Your question was probably not closed for that enumeration, but because of the last sentence in your initial revision _"If you think this is a bad idea, please give a specific reason why."_

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel, I see what you mean.  That was just an afterthought, though.  The point of my question is not to solicit an opinion on whether it's a good idea, but to find some point of entry into the chain of events which lead to the rendering of HTML at which one could interpret HTML tags as functions and evaluate them inside-to-outside.

Comment: It may have been an afterthought, but as the closing sentence of your post, it will draw the focus when making a decision. That said, when I posted my comment I voted to reopen, but it looks like so far it hasn't attracted other reopen votes.

Comment: There are a number of template frameworks that provide capabilities something like this, although probably not fully functional. The functional part is usually done using JS.

Comment: There are templating languages for HTML (e.g. JSX, Mustache, or even PHP counts); why would you ever want to do this though? It's really inefficient; regardless, you could technically use custom elements to do so, but again, I cannot think of a good reason to ever do that. Oh, and there's also [html lang](https://html-lang.org/) if you're really into inflicting self pain.

Comment: @code Suppose you have a page which displays an M x N grid of small text boxes, all the same size. You want to display as many text boxes as fit on the page at one time, regardless of its size, so you want M and N to change dynamically. The user selects the font size, so M and N (and the font size) have to change as the user changes the font size.  How will you do that with any existing language, editing just one file, and without passing any variables back and forth between different languages?

Comment: @code In LISP, code is data, so you can have data in your code and code in your data. In most applications, there's little need to do this--but in dynamic web pages, you want to do it everywhere! The page IS data, but the dynamic content needs code.  Everywhere you have dynamic content, instead of a javascript call, you just wrap the static HTML "template" inside the HTML code, keeping everything in one place.  Pulling code out into javascript forces you to work with big hunks of code and big hunks of data kept in separate places, which makes code inelegant and unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want evaluation to be performed server-side, then you might as well actually write your page in Common Lisp, and with the help of cl-who or Spinneret you can directly write HTML in a way that is quite friendly:

```
CL-USER> (spinneret:with-html
           (:doctype)
           (:html
            (:div
             (:h1 "My features")
             (:ol 
              (dolist (s (subseq *features* 0 6))
                (:li (:pre (string s))))))))
```

The above call writes the following text:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
 <div>
  <h1>My features</h1>
  <ol>
   <li>
    <pre>CLOSER-MOP</pre>
   <li>
    <pre>PARENSCRIPT</pre>
   <li>
    <pre>NAMED-READTABLES</pre>
   <li>
    <pre>HTML-TEMPLATE</pre>
   <li>
    <pre>CL-FAD</pre>
   <li>
    <pre>OSICAT-FD-STREAMS</pre>
  </ol>
 </div>
</html>
NIL
```

In order for your HTML code to be evaluated as Lisp you would need to do a lot more work, following for example [§Using custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements) from the Mozilla developer's documentation, which has an example where you declare your custom elements in JS:

```
customElements.define("popup-info", PopupInfo);
```

And then you can write such elements in HTML:

```
<popup-info>
    ...
</popup-info>
```

Such *Web components* are executed from the outside to the inside, ie. the constructor of an outer component's class is first called, then the components inside it are created ([Order of Custom Elements Execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51055865/order-of-custom-elements-execution)).

You could define a whole set of components like this that mimics a Lisp language, but I think this is going to be a lot of work for something that could be done either in JS directly, or by the server. But I think at least a  proof of concept could be implemented.

Comment: Thanks!  That's two great answers in one!  Spinneret looks very useful to me.